# Entlib Cache.Contains NULL problem

Tags: caching, null, enterprise, contains

I have a combined authorization and menustructure system on our backend.
For performance reasons EntLib caching is used in the frontend client (MVC rel 1.0 website, IIS 5.1 local, IIS 6.0 server, no cluster).

Sometimes 'Cache.Contains' will return true, but the contents of the cache is NULL. I know for certain that I filled it correctly, so what can be the problem here?

EDIT: when I set the cache to 1 minute and add the cacheKey 'A_Key', I will see the key coming back when inspecting the CurrentCacheState. When I view CurrentCacheState after 2 minutes, the key is still there. When I execute 'contains', true is returned. When I execute 'contains' again, the cacheKey is gone!
Synchronization problem??

Regards,
Michel

Excerpt:

```
if (IntranetCaching.Cache.Contains(cacheKey))
{
    menuItems = (List<BoMenuItem>)IntranetCaching.Cache[cacheKey];
}
else
{
    using (AuthorizationServiceProxyHelper authorizationServiceProxyHelper = new AuthorizationServiceProxyHelper())
    {
        menuItems = authorizationServiceProxyHelper.Proxy.SelectMenuByUserAndApplication(APPNAME, userName, AuthorizationType.ENUM_LOGIN);
        IntranetCaching.Add(cacheKey, menuItems);
    }
}
```

And the cachehelper:

```
public static class IntranetCaching
{
    public static ICacheManager Cache { get; private set; }

    static IntranetCaching()
    {
        Cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
    }

    public static void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        Cache.Add(
            key
            , value
            , CacheItemPriority.Normal
            , null
            , new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Expirations.AbsoluteTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Michael for following up your own issue, I have been stuck with this all day identifying that if I try and retrieve an item from Cache this is due to expire (+ 0 up to 25 seconds) I will get a NULL value. Codeplex have posted a workaround (of sorts)as it is in their FAQ:

> a.    How do I avoid getting a null value from the CacheManager when the item is being refreshed? - Intermittently, you may encounter this situation. To work around this, create your own implementation of an ICacheItemExpiration. In the HasExpired()method, implement a logic that will check whether the item has already expired and will update the item's value if it has expired. This method should always return false for the item to not be tagged as expired. As a result of returning false in the HasExpired() method, the item will not be refreshed and will contain the updated value as implemented in the method. 
>   REF: [link](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib%20FAQ&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response from Avanade (creators of Entlib):

> Most likely, the BackgroundScheduler
>   hasn't performed its sweeping yet.  If
>   you're going to examine the source
>   code, the Contains method only checks
>   if the specific key is present in the
>   inmemory cache hashtable while on the
>   GetData method, the code first checks
>   if the item has expired, if it has,
>   the item is removed from the cache.
>
> Sarah Urmeneta Global Technology &
>   Solutions Avanade, Inc.
>   entlib.support@avanade.com

That solution is working for me. 
Still the question remains why you can use 'Contains' when its outcome cannot be used in a sensible way.

Regards,
M.